# canning pickles

Tags: canning

I canned a bushel of pickles 2 weeks ago.  When I finished up that morning,  all the jars were sealed.  This morning I noticed that about a dozen jars were not sealed.  Just the opposite.  The lids were puckering out to the point of bulging the lids out.  I have been canning for more than ten years and I have never seen this before.  What would cause this and are they safe?

Comment: Howevermany years you've been at it, this is a clear sign that this time, something was not right. Toss 'em.

Answer (score 7):

Canning jars bulging, particularly after a period of time, means that some sort of gas is being produced from within.  That likely means that they were not, or are not now, sterile.  I would discard.